# View compiled HTML for Window 8 app

Tags: html, windows-8

I'm building a Windows 8 app using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and I am becoming increasingly annoyed at the UI styles, specifically trying to override them. Without being able to see the compiled HTML, it's virtually impossible to know how to target specific classes.

Is there some way to view the compiled HTML? Please say yes.

Comment: are you using Blend?  You can get some pretty good insight via CSS Properties (esp. Winning Properties) as well as the Interactive Mode.

Comment: I am looking at blend and the GUI is so overwhelming that it turns me off to explore it. I will take another look. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Actually, Blend is quite helpful. I'm still frustrated that they don't just give you the source and let you inspect like you would in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blend's DOM inspector was indeed the best solution, as well as looking at the UI base CSS file to understand how styling was being applied to elements.

Answer (score 1):

From Visual Studio while debugging your app, go to Debug -> Windows -> DOM Explorer.

It brings up the same inspector you get in IE10, which will let you inspect the generated HTML for the built-in controls.